# How to remove parent element if they don't have child in kendo dropdowntree using javascript

Tags: kendo-ui, tree, dropdown

Remove parent element if they have no child elements using java script

Answer (score 1):

Remove them from [`dataSource`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource) using [`remove()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/methods/remove) [filtering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) dataItems which has the `items` property empty. Example:

```
let treeDS = $("#dropdowntree").data("kendoDropDownTree").dataSource;

treeDS
    .data()
    .filter(dataItem => !dataItem.items.length)
        .forEach(dataItem => treeDS.remove(dataItem));
```

[Working demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/eHeqoKOP)

Teardown:

1. Get the dataSource:

   ```
   let treeDS = $("#dropdowntree").data("kendoDropDownTree").dataSource;
   ```
2. Get its data:

   ```
   treeDS.data()
   ```
3. Filter only dataItems with empty `items` property:

   ```
   .filter(dataItem => !dataItem.items.length)
   ```
4. Remove those items from the dataSource:

   ```
   .forEach(dataItem => treeDS.remove(dataItem));
   ```

Comment: but the problem is i bound a data recursively  ,if don't have the grand child parent will be removed     as per ur scenario but for me need to remove grand parent as well need to loop until grand parent